# Retail Android devices with OOB multi-user ability?

Tags: multi-user

I'm looking for an Android tablet that I can share between multiple users. From the little research I've done online, it looks like you can set up multiple users on an Android device, but it's a bit of a hack, and you have to get root access.

Are there any retail Android devices that support multiple users OOB? Or am I wrong about the difficulty level of enabling multi-user on any old Android tablet?

Comment: Why do you think a rooted device is needed? Most Android devices support multiple user profiles. However this system has it's limitations. And some manufacturer may disable the multi-user option on certain devices.

Comment: See the comments here : [How can I know which android phones support multiple users profiles?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221738/218526)

Comment: Hi, take note that device recommendation is off-topic here. You might be interested in our sister site, Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange, but please ensure to follow [their guidelines](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/205) to get the best device for your need.