# Can you create a profile on an Android phone without rooting?

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, profiles

Can you create a profile on an Android phone without rooting? Since the phone I want can't be rooted, is there a way you can create a separate profile like almost any tablet lets you do?

Comment: You mean user profiles? See [this comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221738#comment287128_221738).

Comment: Like a tablet, sorry for the late reply, any tablet mainly lets you make a new user account, is that possible with a phone, like with Samsung there is Knox and external apps like Parallel Space but it only works where you would be in one workspace.